# d3js x axis dates display month at the end not in the front

Tags: d3.js

When displaying a axis with months as ticks, the month is attached to the last day of the month.  Would like it to be in the beginning of the month.

Working sample can be see at: http://codepen.io/pcasa/pen/apYdwG

[image]

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
               .append("svg:svg")
               .attr("height", 100)
               .attr("width", 800);

svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
   .attr('class', 'main axis date');

svg.append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
              .attr('class', 'main axis month')
              .selectAll('text')
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr('dx', 5)
                .attr('dy', 12);

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
            .range([0,760])
            .domain([new Date(2016, 7, 20),new Date(2016, 9, 2)])
            .clamp(true);

var x1DateAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
               .ticks(d3.utcDay, 1)
               .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d'))
               .tickSize(16, 0, 0);

var x1MonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.utcMonth, 1)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%B'))
              .tickSize(24, 0, 0);

svg.select('.axis.month')
          .call(x1MonthAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end');

svg.select('.axis.date')
          .call(x1DateAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end')
            .attr('dy', -6)
            .attr('dx', -1);
```

Comment: I do not have the same axis in the codepen..  but in the codepen if you change `.style('text-anchor', 'end')` ; to .`style('text-anchor', 'start');` that should be enough..

Comment: Unfortunately, that just flips which side of the tick it renders the month.  Seems that part of the problem is using d3.utcMonth in the .ticks().  If I change it to d3.timeMonth it renders as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This one work for me in the codepen

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
               .append("svg:svg")
               .attr("height", 100)
               .attr("width", 800);

svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
   .attr('class', 'main axis date');

svg.append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
              .attr('class', 'main axis month')
              .selectAll('text')
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr('dx', 5)
                .attr('dy', 12);

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
            .range([0,760])
            .domain([new Date(2016, 7, 20),new Date(2016, 9, 2)])
            .clamp(true);

var x1DateAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
               .ticks(d3.utcDay, 1)
               .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d'))
               .tickSize(16, 0, 0);

var x1MonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.utcMonth, 1)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%B'))
              .tickSize(24, 0, 0);

svg.select('.axis.month')
          .call(x1MonthAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'start');

svg.select('.axis.date')
          .call(x1DateAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'start')
            .attr('dy', -6)
            .attr('dx', +3);
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this changes on which side of the tick the month is rendered at.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct. In D3, the `scaleUTC()` (which is equivalent to `scaleTime()` operating in Coordinated Universal Time) scale **does** display the month tick at the *beginning* of the month, not at its end.

This is probably the cause of your mistake: despite the fact that in `d3.format` the months start at 01...

> month as a decimal number [01,12].

... which makes January being 01 and December being 12, in plain JavaScript, `new Date()` sets the months **from 0 to 11**. That is, January is 0 and December is 11.

We can easily see that this is the case in this following snippet, where I copied your code exactly as it is, changing only the start and end dates:

```
.domain([new Date(2016, 0, 20),new Date(2016, 2, 2)])
//January here ---------^      March here-----^
```

You can see that the scale starts at 20th January and ends at 2nd March. Look at the result, both "February" and "March" labels are exactly at the beginning of the respective months:

```js
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
               .append("svg:svg")
               .attr("height", 100)
               .attr("width", 800);

svg.append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
   .attr('class', 'main axis date');

svg.append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)')
              .attr('class', 'main axis month')
              .selectAll('text')
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr('dx', 5)
                .attr('dy', 12);

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
            .range([0,760])
            .domain([new Date(2016, 0, 20),new Date(2016, 2, 2)])
            .clamp(true);

var x1DateAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
               .ticks(d3.utcDay, 1)
               .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d'))                        .tickSize(16, 0, 0);

var x1MonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.utcMonth, 1)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%B'))
              .tickSize(24, 0, 0);

svg.select('.axis.month')
          .call(x1MonthAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end');

svg.select('.axis.date')
          .call(x1DateAxis)
          .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end')
            .attr('dy', -6)
            .attr('dx', -1);
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Not disagreeing with your statement above, but if you change d3.utcMonth to d3.timeMonth, it will yield the desired results.  Where your code shows January as the first tick, changing to d3.timeMonth  shows February as the first tick which is what I would like to display.  This ticket might share some light to the where i "believe" the problem is https://github.com/d3/d3-time/issues/19

Comment: My code shows **February** as the first tick, see it again. Besides that, changing `utcMonth` for `timeMonth` makes no difference. I already explained the problem in details, I don't know why you opened that issue at Github or what remains unclear.

Comment: Perhaps we are seeing 2 different things, but clicking "run code snippet" shows the first tick WITH TEXT as January.  http://codepen.io/pcasa/pen/jyzgqP shows a third level with timeMonth of how I expected the graph to render.